# Change number of default vertices in circles

Tags: qgis, area, vertices, tools

I would like to change the number of default vertices per quarter circle QGIS creates/uses when running tools.

**Background**

I need to do some area calculations for circles and polygons containing curves, which have been imported from DXF drawings. When correctly imported, QGIS is able to display/retain the curves. Once tools get involved (notably `intersect` for my usecase), the curves become segments, by default (?) these are 90 segments per quarter circle. This leads to discrepancies between the actual circle and the segmented one. E.g. for a circle of 300 m width QGIS gives 3.6 sqm less than the circle actually is large. The relative uncertainty is about 0.005 %, but I'd still like to eliminate it as much as possible.

**Question**

I did some trials, and discovered that using as much as 200 segments per quarter circle would reduce the error to about 0.001 % - which seems more acceptable than the 0.005 % above.

So how do I tell QGIS to use a specified number of segements for certain calculations/operations? Preferrably without using Python, but one can't be picky.

Comment: Select your circles, get the radius of each, get the centroid, create a buffer by adjusting the number of segments.

Comment: @Taras I am unsure how I could visualize the issue. Ideas?

Comment: @J.Monticolo this still leaves the issue that intersect seems to work using 90 segments max - so it is no feasible option. And it definitely wont work with polygons containing curves.